# Where are the scenarios inwhich we can use AutoIT framework?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

Currently i am using AutoIt for only file uploading scenarion.Like this,which are the condition where we can use AutoIt

Comment: where*=What please replace

Answer (score 0):

Any windows,  mouse & keystrokes related tasks which we are not able to handle with web-driver that can be handled with AutoIt.